# Mouse and Button Event Tracking on win32 GUI program

Tags: c++, winapi, button, window, mouseevent

I have a Win32 GUI program built by Borland C++ Builder 6.

I want to do some user behavior analyses on it by logging users' input.

Such as mouse clicking on which window, buttons clicking messages and components clicking message etc.

First time I tried to insert some C codes in the Click Events of GUI components.

However, there are too many components for me to insert these codes.

Therefore, I want to ask for some methods/libraries to capture mouse and button events depending on message loop or something...

Comment: What You might be looking for is called "hooking".

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs

Comment: thx ! I learned a lot from it.